# how to send a local file in bale bot to a client?

Tags: python, bots, bale-messenger

I've tried some code but I was not successful to send a file message with my bot. After upload my file I'm not able to get file_id and access_hash and other from the server to send it.
It's my code:

```
@dispatcher.message_handler(PhotoFilter())
def ask_photo(bot, update):
    user_peer = update.get_effective_user()
    bot.upload_file(file="../files/upload_file_test.jpeg", 
        file_type="file", 
        success_callback=file_upload_success,failure_callback=failure)   


def file_upload_success(response):
    photo_message = PhotoMessage(file_id=response.file_id,  
        access_hash=response.access_hash, name="photo", file_size="100",
        mime_type="image/jpeg", thumb=response.thumb, width=80, height=80,
        caption_text="caption")
    bot.send_message(photo_message, user_peer)
```

It doesn't work! :( 
 any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this code can help you

```html
import asyncio
from balebot.filters import
from balebot.models.messages import
from balebot.updater import Updater

updater = Updater(token="PUT YOUR TOKEN HERE",loop=asyncio.get_event_loop())
bot = updater.bot
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

def success(response, user_data):
    print("success : ", response)
    print(user_data)

def failure(response, user_data):
    print("failure : ", response)
    print(user_data)

@dispatcher.message_handler(DefaultFilter())
def send_txt_file(bot, update):
    user_peer = update.get_effective_user()

def file_upload_success(result, user_data):
    print("upload was successful : ", result)
    print(user_data)
    
    file_id = str(user_data.get("file_id", None))
    access_hash = str(user_data.get("user_id", None))
    file_message = DocumentMessage(file_id=file_id, access_hash=access_hash, name="Bale", file_size='PUT YOUR FILE SIZE HERE',
    mime_type="PUT YOUR FILE MIME TYPE HERE", caption_text=TextMessage(text="HELLO"),
    file_storage_version=1)
    bot.send_message(file_message, user_peer, success_callback=success, failure_callback=failure)

bot.upload_file(file="PUT YOUR FILE LOCATION ADDRESS HERE", file_type="file", success_callback=file_upload_success,
    failure_callback=failure)

updater.run()
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use success callback to handle what you need after uploading the file.Result and user_data are parameters you can get file_id and access_hash from.
here is a complete example:

```
@dispatcher.message_handler(PhotoFilter())
def ask_photo(bot, update):
    user_peer = update.get_effective_user()

    def file_upload_success(result, user_data):
        """Its the link of upload photo but u cant see anything with it because you need to take a token from server.
            actually this link is just for uploading a file not download. If you want to download this file you should
            use get_file_download_url() and take a token from server.
        """
        print("upload was successful : ", result)
        print(user_data)
        file_id = str(user_data.get("file_id", None))
        access_hash = str(user_data.get("user_id", None))
        print("fileIDD: ", file_id, "access", access_hash)
        v_message = PhotoMessage(file_id=file_id, access_hash=access_hash, name="Bale", file_size='11337',
                                 mime_type="image/jpeg", caption_text=TextMessage(text="Bale"),
                                 file_storage_version=1, thumb=None)

        bot.send_message(v_message, user_peer, success_callback=success, failure_callback=failure)

    bot.upload_file(file="../files/upload_file_test.jpeg", file_type="file", success_callback=file_upload_success,
                    failure_callback=failure)
    message = TextMessage("Thanks \nplease send a Hello voice message.")
    user_peer = update.get_effective_user()
    bot.send_message(message, user_peer, success_callback=success, failure_callback=failure)
    dispatcher.register_conversation_next_step_handler(update, MessageHandler(VoiceFilter(), finish_conversion))
```

Comment: It seems that you sent photo message in your code but the question ask about upload file

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ehsan, Your answer was useful too

Answer (score 0):

in python-bale-bot, you can follows these steps:

1. First, send the file to the bot in Bale messenger in order to find its `file_id`.

```
@bot.listen(bale.EventType.MESSAGE)
async def on_callback(message: bale.Message):
    if message.document:
        print(message.document.file_id)
```

2. Now that we have the `file_id`, we can send the file to them, as if the bot is forwarding a document message.

```
@bot.listen(bale.EventType.CALLBACK)
async def on_callback(callback: bale.CallbackQuery):
    await callback.message.chat.send_document(document = "Your file id", ...)
```

In this method, there is no need to open the file in your python script. Your file can be recognized using its ID.